# Where is the x-calconnect-venue schema defined?

Tags: xsd, feed, xml-namespaces

I'm creating an atom feed and want to include event venue data similar to the RSS example on the [Zvent API](http://events.ohio.com/api_doc/output). EventBrite includes a similar snippet with the same xCal namespace (urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xcal).

Here's the snippet:

```
 <xCal:x-calconnect-venue>
    <xCal:x-calconnect-venue-id>4553</xCal:x-calconnect-venue-id>
    <xCal:adr>
      <xCal:x-calconnect-venue-name>Improv Comedy Club and Restaurant</xCal:x-calconnect-venue-name>
      <xCal:x-calconnect-street>62 S. 2nd St.</xCal:x-calconnect-street>
      <xCal:x-calconnect-city>San Jose</xCal:x-calconnect-city>
      <xCal:x-calconnect-region>California</xCal:x-calconnect-region>
      <xCal:x-calconnect-postalcode>95113</xCal:x-calconnect-postalcode>
      <xCal:x-calconnect-country>United States</xCal:x-calconnect-country>
      <xCal:x-calconnect-fips-county>085</xCal:x-calconnect-fips-county>
      <xCal:x-calconnect-fips-state-county>CA085</xCal:x-calconnect-fips-state-county>
    </xCal:adr>
    <xCal:url>http://improv2.com/v3/index.php?option=content&task=blogcategory&id=40&Itemid=50</xCal:url>
    <xCal:x-calconnect-tel>(408) 280-7475</xCal:x-calconnect-tel>
  </xCal:x-calconnect-venue>
```

Although I suppose I can just go ahead and copy the format and fill it out to the best of my ability (so event aggregators can still consume my feed without much trouble), I would love to know where this is defined. Anyone know? I've searched.

Possibly, I'm misunderstanding the extensibility of the [iCalendar schema](http://www.calconnect.org/artifacts/ical-art.shtml), which incidentally has a different namespace (urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:icalendar-2.0).

Can anyone set me straight?

Thanks!

---

### UPDATE

Added x-calconnect-fips-county and x-calconnect-fips-state-county for a recent need that I had. I updated the code above as a way to document this in the absence of a standard.

Comment: This article covers a lot of ground with respect to event data in feeds: http://blogs.oucs.ox.ac.uk/inapickle/2009/12/16/adding-event-times-and-location-to-rss-and-atom-feeds/

Answer (score 1):

The iCalendar format ( http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2445.txt, http://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/) - that is not XML - supports the addition of custom properties prefixing their name with `x-`.

I suspect that in this case whoever created this extension just added new elements prefixing their name with `x-`, without bothering to refer to an actual schema - i.e. they used the iCalendar extensibility syntax instead of using the proper XML way of definining a separate namespace with its schema etc.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I suspect that to be the case as well. I should think one of the event aggregators would come up with a de facto standard just to make sure feed creators conform to something they can reasonably expect to parse!